# Set (temporary) fixed zoom factor in Visual Studio 2010 code editor

Tags: visual-studio, editor, zooming

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2010 (or ReSharper, btw.) to zoom in newly opened files to a specific percentage?

(Background: In some cases (working late, different screen) I'd like to zoom in a little to make it easier on the eyes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) allows you to specify zoom level for newly opened documents.

Comment: Is this functionality in the free version?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime I found a working solution:

The Visual Studio add-in [presentation zoom](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/6a7a0b57-7059-470d-bcfa-60ceb78dc752) provides a behavior similar to which I was looking for. To quote the description at vs gallery:

> This extension creates a global zoom level so that if you zoom a single window, all editor instances will be updated to that zoom level.

The zoom level is applied to newly opened files as well (which was particularly important for me)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with plainly changing the default text size via Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Size

As to ReSharper, it doesn't provide this kind of rendering options.

Comment: I thought about that, but discarded it for not beeing flexible enough.